# Running an Append Query in Access

Tags: ms-access, append

I'm working on an Access database with about 12 million records.

When I run an append/update query it sits and thinks for quiet a while and then gives me a message box, "You are about to updated (x) records. Do you wish to continue"

If I were to cancel that process before that message box appears, has it changed any records.

Thanks

John

Comment: `Cancel` the operation how? Hitting the `Esc` key? If so, the operation was never carried out. So you are safe.

Comment: Yes, by hitting escape.Thanks, that's a relief

Answer (score 2):

Access begins a transaction, updates the records, then asks you to confirm the transaction.

If yes, it is committed; if no, it is rolled back.

That's why it takes a long time before the messagebox appears but only a moment after you have pressed the key.

Answer (score 1):

No, Access doesn't actually apply the changes until you confirm that message box with **Yes**.

So even if you wait until you see the message box and then cancel it with **No**, nothing will have changed.